# Will adding a column externally to a table mapped by JPA break normal functioning?

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink

I'm new to JPA and I'm learning a lot about it. I recently deployed an application with EclipseLink as my JPA provider and it is running well.

Now there is a need to add an extra column to one of the mapped tables. This extra field is for reporting purposes and does not affect my application, so I really don't want to touch something that is working well. I will of course update my application in due time to include this field in my mappings but I don't want to do it just now.

This column addition will be done externally by the DBA directly to the tables. Will this addition break my application?

I believe that this should not happens since there is no change in the mapped fields and as far as JPA is concerned nothing has changed. JPA will not be aware of what was added so everything should work without breaking.

Please correct me if I'm wrong. Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can do it there's no reason it could break, JPA does not force you to map every column to a field in your entity. Except if the new column is mandatory (`NOT NULL`) and does not have a default value (on insert for example).

Answer (score 6):

> Will this addition break my application?

No, it will not.

JPA allows you to map only the tables and fields you actually need.

Answer (score 5):

What does an ORM such as JPA, Hibernate, or EclipseLink do under the hood ? It generates the SQL starting from your data model to let you interact with a database in a transparent way.

If you apply any modification to the database which do not require modification to the SQL you use to interact with it (you are not adding any constraints and non null columns), nothing will break. Your SQL queries will simply not use the added columns when writing/reading from the db.

If on the contrary you apply changes on the constraints, you can make your code not working anymore even without adding a column.